# SimpleHTMLDom Library

Tags: simple-html-dom

I am using this library : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I have the following page which I want to extract in each line:

```
<div class="amx-form-entry-container">
            <table style="font-size: 16px; color:#000">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>Submitted by:</td>
                    <td>
                       Rami
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Assignee:
                    </td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Subcategory:
                    </td>
                    <td> H:  Documentation</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Description:
                    </td>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Case reference:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        BEY/0517/4444

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Status:
                    </td>
                    <td> Closed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Created on:
                    </td>
                    <td> 19 May 2017</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody></table>
        </div>
```

For example: 
Submited by : Rami 
Assignee: .. 
Description: Hello

I have done this code :
`$oDom = new simple_html_dom();
$dd=$oDom->load($result);
$test= $oDom->find("div[class='amx-module amx-mr-form-panel']",0); 
echo $test;`

But it prints the output as a table, If i view the page source I will see same above code.
- What I want to achieve is print each element in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code

```
$oDom->load($result);
$tables = $oDom->find('table');

$theData = array();
foreach($tables[0]->find('tr') as $row){
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }
    $theData[] = $rowData;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($theData); echo "</pre>";


### Result ###

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Submitted by:
        [1] => Rami                      
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Assignee:                      
        [1] =>  
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Subcategory:                      
        [1] => H:  Documentation
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Description:                      
        [1] => Hello
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Case reference:                      
        [1] => BEY/0517/4444                        
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Status:                      
        [1] => Closed
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Created on:                      
        [1] => 19 May 2017
    )
)
```